Is air less dense than chimney exhaust?
So there is this question in my text book that says us to arrange these following items by increasing density:
Air, exhaust from chimneys, honey, water, chalk, cotton and iron.
Everything is straightforward except for air and chimney exhaust.
My answer was that air is denser than chimney exhaust since the exhaust would be hot, so there would be more spacing between the particles, making it less dense. This can also explain why exhaust goes up through the chimney due to the buoyant force of the air.
But every single online source and my teacher says chimney exhaust is denser than air and their reasoning being it contains carbon particles which make it heavier as seen below:


Who is in the correct? And if my teacher and literally every other online source is correct (basically the matrix) is correct, how are they correct and so how does the exhaust exit the chimney?

When chimney exhaust is hot it is less dense. As you say, you know this because it rises. What do you think when it cools off?

The contents of the exhaust like carbon deposit? So density depends whether we take the measure initially after the combustion or later. Is that what your trying to convey?

You should be comparing the densities at the same temperature.

@ChetMiller No, you should NOT be comparing the densities at conditions that are inconsistent with those stated.    Exhaust from chimneys is hot.

@Whit3rd Agreed. If the question-setters wanted the comparison performed at the same temperature (as their answer implies) this should have been explicitly mentioned in the question, especially if one of the items is "naturally" at a different temperature.

@Whit3rd In modern boilers, chimney exhaust is not hot.  Releasing hot air out of the chimney is a serious waste of energy and only found in old legacy boilers AFAIK (I don't think it's legal in new boilers where I live).  The answer may depend on whether this is a condensing boiler or not.

@gerrit Nope. The exhaust from condensing boilers may be less hot than the exhaust from older models, but it is still hot. This isn't hart to check if you have one (I have).

@matt_black Maybe it depends on the model, but enwiki suggests it's around 38°C and necessitates mechanical fans.  I can't check it myself as our own heating system only exhausts air that is substantially colder than the environment (and not through the chimney).

@gerrit Then we also have to get into terminology.  If it's not being used to exhaust hot gasses, is it even a chimney, or just a vent?  Also terms like "chimney effect" which explicitly work because of the lower density of the hot exhaust gasses.

@JMac Hm, I didn't realise a chimney had hot exhaust gases by definition, and that if I use it to exhaust cool or warm (but not hot) gases (after retrofitting a condensing boiler in a property that had a non-condensing boiler before) then I'm just using the chimney as an ordinary vent.  If a factory releases cool toxic fumes from a high chimney then it's not a chimney?

@gerrit That's definitely the implication I get from it.  Like wikipedia doesnt exactly define it like that, but all the things that it lists chimneys exhaust the gas from are all things that create hot gas, so the connection is strongly implied to me.  Consider for example plumbing ventilation.  I've never heard the roof vent referred to as a "chimney" by anyone who knows its function.

How does your teacher explain how a chimney functions if the exhaust it is trying to draw is more dense than the surrounding air?  (i.e. I agree with you and most of the answers and would love to hear your teacher talk themselves out of this one)

@TyHayes Chimney exhaust is moving. At the start of the chimney, the air is heated, where it expands to be far less dense. The space is constricted, so the air that wants to be less dense hits the walls of the chimney, which increases its pressure. That pushes upwards. As the air gets pushed up, it begins to cool, which increases its density. By the end of the chimney, depending on its size and design, you can have exhaust cooled to ambient temperature, still moving upwards. Turn the chimney on its side, add some fans, and you have a jet engine.

not sure cotton is in the right place either... according to a quick search it is around 50% more dense than water.

@TyHayes Or have them explain how a hot air balloon works given that it is filled at least partially with exhaust.

Natural gas furnaces that are noncondensing typically use an inducer motor/fan to initially drive the exhaust gases up a chimney and to clear it once the flame is halted.

What about in a rural country-side where the exhaust is not driven up by a fan.
(It's just an assumption I made since most of my country is rural)

@PhineSine No fan is necessary for the effect to work. Its the design of the chimney that makes it work. The flame is at the base of a tube, the air goes into the flame and heats up, Usually, the top of the flame is partially into the tube or ends at the base of the tube. This means that some of the air is still expanding or heating up when inside of the constricted space of the chimney. The key is heating the air while its constricted which enables the air to push up and out of the chimney without a fan.

If you assume that you are burning wood (a glucose polymer) and that burning glucose is a close approximation, a balanced chemical reaction using air indicates that the molar mass of chimney gas is 28.78 while the molar mass of air is 28.84.  The chimney gas contains CO2 with a molar mass of 44, but it also contains water vapor, with a molar mass of 18.  The assumption that chimney gas is more dense than air is an indication that the water vapor content of the chimney gas was ignored, leading to an incorrect conclusion.

The question that you are quoting is a very poor question, since the answer depends on what is being burnt to produce the exhaust from the chimney and how far away from the chimney we measure the density.
It is true that smoke from low-quality coal or wood fuel will contain carbon particles. Although it is initially less dense than the surrounding air when hot (otherwise the chimney would not draw), it will cool quickly after it leaves the chimney and may quickly become more dense than the surrounding air.
However, chimney exhaust from smokeless fuel has fewer carbon particles and is hotter, so it will be less dense than the surrounding air for much longer. This is why smokeless fuel was widely adopted to improve air quality in the UK from the mid-1950s onwards. And the chimney exhaust from a properly designed gas fire contains no carbon particles at all.

Exhaust from oil or gas fire also contains a lot of water vapour, which is less dense than air (even of the same temperature) - although some of this would generally condense to droplets quickly, forming white steam.

NB: Another reason this is a poor question: modern boilers do not have a hot exhaust and a hot exhaust is a serious waste of energy.  Therefore, the assumption that chimney exhaust is hot is probably invalid for real boilers and the question is unanswerable if this is not stated.

would the (I assume) higher CO2 content of "chimney exhaust" compared to regular air make a difference here? AFAIK CO2 is denser than the standard air mix... obviously not enough so that it would offset the higher temperature (otherwise chimneys would not work).

I think you mean that the question the OP is asking about is poor, not that the OP's question is poor, correct?

@JimmyJames Correct. I have changed the first sentence of my answer to clarify this.

Particulate matter
The density of airborne particulate matter (PM10 and PM2.5) in smoke is rather low, less than a few grams per cubic meter at most. (The linked paper contains direct ground-level measurements of the particulate density of wildfire smoke which turned out to be less than 50 milligrams per cubic meter.) The majority of these particles are less than a micron in diameter which makes smoke a colloid. Therefore it is rather unlikely that its mass is of significance compared to the change in density with temperature.
Density and composition
Flue gas (exhaust gas emitted from chimneys in fireplaces, furnaces, power plants, etc) usually comprises nitrogen, carbon dioxide and water vapor. It is at several hundred degrees Celsius immediately after combustion so its density is less than half the density of air.
However, if you were to compare them at the same temperature, the exhaust has similar density as air according to this table which uses a sample composition. Without more information on the chemical composition of the exhaust, it is not possible to make a definitive conclusion because carbon dioxide is denser than air by about the same amount as water vapor is less dense than air.
Conclusion
The exhaust cools as it rises. So the question, as stated, is ambiguous as it does not specify the temperature which is (together with chemical composition) the largest determinant of density here. The given reason (particulate matter increasing the density) is technically correct though, just not by any significant amount.

The conclusion is even more valid because nowadays, chimney exhaust is not actually very hot.

Chimney exhaust is pumped by the density of the cool ambient air
being greater than that of the heated gasses coming from a fire.
Density times column height of the chimney puts less pressure
at the bottom of the chimney, thus cool air pushes in at the
bottom and hot vapors come out at the top
The pump which we call a chimney wouldn't work otherwise.
As for 'air', there's no conditions stated, so we'd assume
standard temperature and pressure.  STP is the usual
nomenclature in a chem  lab with loose definition

I very much agree with the idea that "chimney exhaust" should be interpreted to mean "the stuff coming out of a chimney" - if it's passively rising out of a chimney, it must be less dense than air. It would seem silly to think the question could be referring to a layer of soot or ash on the ground, simply because it came out of a chimney at some point. How would one even define the density of chimney exhaust once it's left the chimney and has dissipated and cooled in the atmosphere? Gas density is a bulk property not really related to the density of individual molecules.

This actually has an interesting connection to volcanism.
Volcanic plumes (similar to chimney exhaust) are far more dense than the air around them, but they rise, sometimes as high as 20 kilometers. How? By entraining and heating air.
The contents of the volcanic plume are really friggin' hot (usually in the 800 F range) and dense (most of it is volcanic ash, i.e., rock). The plume really only has enough upward momentum to carry it a few hundred meters up. Not all that far. It tries to fall, but in so doing, creates little vortices that suck cool air into the plume. That air gets heated to super high temperatures, which then makes the combination of plume material and air less dense than the cool ambient air, then letting the plume continue its rise. In cases where the plume can't suck in enough air, the plume stays dense and you get a pyroclastic density current.

Your answer is correct, simply because the high temperature of the chimney exhaust overcomes any difference in density between atmospheric air and flu gas because of chemical composition. The flu gas contains mainly nitrogen, carbon dioxide and water vapor. Particulates are not part of the fluid and thus are not relevant to the "chimney effect." If you do the calculation using the proper temperatures, you will see that the flu gas density is smaller.
BTW, that's why the flu gases go upward through the chimney and carry any particulates with them. The net pressure force acting on all the flu gas in the chimney is equal to the height of the chimney times the density difference between the flu gas and the outside air. (The mass of the particulates is very small compared with the mass of the flu gases.)

Minor comment: a "flue" is a valve for opening and closing a chimney, while a "flu" is a respiratory disease caused by an influenza virus.

Exactly, I like how millions of people, maybe even a billion people and an entire council of educators which makes official textbooks for my country got it wrong. But something doesn't make sense, how could they all get it wrong? The textbook probably wants us to go with the assumption that more stuff or more varieties of stuff = more dense
